# What are the popular production software deployment systems?

Tags: untagged

I am curious to know what are the popular production deployment system i.e. popular ways in which things are moved from test/qa sandbox and final releases are pushed into production available to be used. I have heard of things like autosys,vcs,zapp. Are these industry standard production deployment systems? What do biggies like Google,Microsoft,Yahoo,Amazon etc use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tool used widely at Yahoo is [pogo](https://github.com/nrh/pogo/), which is a massively parallel ssh-based execution tool. It can be used to invoke commands in parallel on thousands of machines at once.  Pogo also contains a constraint mechanism to say things like "only run on 20% of this type of server at once".  There's also a pre/post hook and recipe mechanism in pogo to perform custom check and command before and after a push.  One way this is used frequently is to run health checks which verify that services on a machine come back up after a software push.

A similar tool that others use is [Capistrano](http://www.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Capistrano).  I don't know a lot about it but that tool gets mentioned a lot.

Many people use the remote execution facility in their configuration management tool to accomplish this task as well. This can be done for example with [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com) or [Cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org/) or [Chef](http://www.opscode.com).  Those solutions tend to work ok at smaller scales.  At larger scale (thousands of servers) you should really look in to a more specialized tool like the ones I've mentioned above.

Of course you can also use tools like [ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page) to accomplish tasks like this, although I recommend against that approach because it's not really scriptable or repeatable.